# Network error: Software cause connection abort after too many failed login attempts.

Tags: ip, putty, filezilla

I was on PuTTy and after putting the incorrect login too many times, they IP blocked me. So now I cannot use puTTy or Filezilla. Is there a way where I can unblock my IP address?

Comment: Ask the admins of the site blocking you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about UNIX or Linux.

Comment: So many other people have posted about Putty and SSH on here. I'm not sure what you are talking about. Plus why would you go as far as trying to block me for asking a question.

Comment: Your question is not about PuTTY.

Comment: Yes it is, did you even read my message before commenting on it?

Comment: You broke some site's policies and they blocked you.  This has nothing to do with PuTTY, Filezilla, Zarathustra, or the phase of the moon.  It has to do with you not following their rules.  Ask them to re-enable your access.

Comment: I didn't break any policies. I did multiple invalid logins on PuTTy and they have a ip blockage on me. This is common in PuTTy. And there is a way in SSH prompt to lift the IP address ban. I wanted to know what I have to do in the command prompt to lift the ban.

Comment: @HNK123 Policy means the rules under which the server should be used and since your IP seams to be blocked your actions might have violated one of these policy rules. These things happen to the best of us, so just call the admin. It has nothing to do with PuTTy.

Comment: @HNK123 So if YOU ran a server, and decided that after someone entered the wrong details 3 times you'd lock them out to prevent other people from brute-forcing their password, you'd say "it's ok, they'll be able to use a special putty command to undo the block"?  Did it not occur to you that if this mechanism was available to the user it would be available to the attacker too?   You can see that this is not about putty because you could use a different client and experience the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments:

> *"I did multiple invalid logins on PuTTy and they have a ip blockage on me. This is common in PuTTy. "*

As already said by @Satō in his comment, this does not depend on PuTTY neither any other SSH client. The ban is set on the server's config, e.g. on the firewall config triggered by `fail2ban`.

> *"And there is a way in SSH prompt to lift the IP address ban.  I wanted to know what I have to do in the command prompt to lift the ban. "*

There is no way that you can remove the block by yourself. That would be ludicrous and thwart completely the protection done by the IP address ban against attackers.

Yes, you can lift the ban if you have root access **and you are already able to login into the machine**. In this case you'd simply change the config and unblock your IP. But here you locked yourself out, so it's a Catch-22 situation.

However, what you can do is to **login from a different IP address**.

The ban is on your IP, so by SSH'ing to a different machine and then by SSH'ing again to the target server (the one blocking you) you will be able to login. Clearly you need to have permission to login from the jump machine to the target server, and this is something we aren't able to tell you.

Failing to do this, **talk to the admins of the target server** and explain the situation so that they (hopefully) remove the ban.